# How can I find memory usage in all environments (R)?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, environment

I want to find the total memory used by R in all environments. How do I do that?

I can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395270/determining-memory-usage-of-objects) to find memory usage in the current environment, or any environment I know the name of. But I don't know how to do that across *all* environments. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491195/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-environments-environment-names-in-r) provides a way to get environment names recursively, but it sounds like there are edge cases where it will fail. Is there a robust solution for this?